# How to get specific data with specific buttons

Tags: javascript, html

working on this app:
https://jsfiddle.net/70jagnLo/

So, how it goes at the moment, I click the ADD button on the left, modal appears, get modal text input value, create a new div(project name) and append it to a list underneath the ADD button. Now, I have a let counter that counts each new div that is appended.

What my problem is, I want to create a new modal on the right of the page that opens informations 
about each individual div(project name) and let it's data to be changeable.

Each div has a new class with each creation(project1, project2, project3 and so on).

How do I access each project individually and open a modal with different information for it?

```
const newProject = () =>{
        let projectTitle = document.querySelector('#project-name').value;
        projectCounter++;

        let projectDiv = document.createElement('div');
        projectDiv.classList.add('project' + projectCounter)
        projectDiv.innerHTML = projectTitle;

        projectsList.appendChild(projectDiv)
        ProjectModal.closeModal();

        document.querySelector('#project-name').value = '';

    }
```

```
projectsList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let tgt = e.target;
    let cls = e.target.classList
    if (cls.contains('project1')){
        ToDoFactory.createToDo();
    }
})
```

Here in the last function, I can create a new div for a project, but I have to do it manually and put 'project1' for cls.contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally recommend to implement `localStorage` to actually store your information in a JSON object. That way you can always access your data at a later moment.

JS

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        projects = localStorage.getItem("projects");
        if (projects.length == 0) { // create new projects object
            projects = {};
        } else {
            projects = JSON.parse(projects);
        }

        function saveProject(data)
        {
            projects[data.title] = data;
            localStorage.setItem("projects", JSON.stringify(projects));
        }

        function render()
        {
            let list = document.getElementById('list');
            list.innerHTML = "";
            for (let key in projects) {
                let li = list.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
                li.dataset.id = projects[key].title;
                li.innerText = projects[key].description;
                li.onclick = function () {
                    let project = projects[this.dataset.id];
                    let form = document.getElementById('form');
                    form.elements.title.value = project.title;
                    form.elements.description.value = project.description;
                    /* set the form's data and show it */
                }
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
            let id = Date.now(); // or you can generate one yourself
            saveProject(id, {
                title: form.elements.title.value,
                description: form.elements.title.description
            });
            render();
        }

        render();
    });
```

HTML

```
    <body>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
        <form id="form">
            <input name="title" />
            <input name="description" />
            <button type="submit">save</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use e.target.className to get the newly added div class.

```
 projectsList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let tgt = e.target;
        let clsname = e.target.className;
        if (cls.contains(clsname)){
            ToDoFactory.createToDo();
        }
    })
```